# What is the number of ordered pairs $(x,y)$ of integers such that their product is a positive integer less than 100?

Tags: number-theory

Is there a way to use floor functions (or something similar), to find the solution instead of brute forcing the numbers.

already tried the brute force method and getting the answer as 946

Comment: HINT: Picture what all such ordered pairs might look like if plotted on the $xy$ plane. That should give you a start.